# inerasable text on VSCode in print, printf and println

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, printf, redhat

I was studying java in VSCode a few days ago, today i went back to study and my code looks weird with some text in specific lines before the double quotes in print, printf and println. [the "format:" and "x:"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiLDJ.png)I don't know how to remove from the program. To be more specific, I think that the issue is somewhere in the extension "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" bc when I disable, the text just disappears (the problem is that I need this extension to compile the program).

obs: It's my first post here, sorry for any mistakes haha

Comment: they are the parameter names of the function, a new feature, search SO for the setting related or the release/update notes of VSC

Comment: your answer helped me a lot to find the problem man, thx!!

Answer (score 1):

This is the new feature of `JAVA` extension([link](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2412#issuecomment-1099792332)):

> It's a new feature introduced in 1.5.0, called inlay hint. We use that
> to display the parameter names of those arguments.
>
> If you do not want to have them in your editor, you can set the
> setting **java.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled to none**

`"editor.inlayHints.enabled": false` can also achieve this, but it will disable all the inlayHints no matter which extension provided it.